# How to test a method which runs slower than instantaneously?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have a case where invoking a method returns an error, but only after a certain period of time (it polls an external service for some time, and in case of failure returns an error).

Can I unit-test this scenario? Is a test valid which measures the method's execution time and compares it to some value?

```
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.start();
myService.do(1000); // argument is a timeout in ms
stopWatch.stop();

...

assertTrue(stopWatch.getTime() >= 1000);
```

Comment: You meant "poll", not "pool", right?

Comment: @Dave Schweisguth Sure. You are welcome to edit my posts, if you think there is an issue.

Comment: In general I would, but I didn't want to change the meaning of your question if I was wrong.

Comment: @Dave_Schweisguth Oh, got it. Thanks for pointing to mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is somewhat valid, but it's not optimal for two reasons:

- Time can pass for more than one reason, so (as your use of `>=` reveals) you can't test your waiting logic exactly, only approximately.
- One second is a long time. Slow tests are a drag on the team.

You can fix the second issue easily by waiting for 1 ms rather than 1000, but then you can barely tell whether your waiting logic is working.

I would stub the method you're calling to measure the passage of time (e.g. `System.currentTimeMillis`) and mock the method you're calling to wait (e.g. `Thread.sleep`) so that your test shows that your waiting logic is correct, but you don't actually have to wait.

Comment: I can't mock the method being tested. Waiting is an outcome of tested method execution - it does multiple attempts to access external service (which is mocked and returns error on call).

Comment: I made what I meant more explicit in my answer.

Comment: Mock the external service, not the method being tested. You don't want to mock the method being tested, beacuse then your not testing it ! :)

Comment: @rob looks like we crossed comments. See if my meaning is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html) to stub parts of your service that you are not interested in testing.

In one unit test you could mock the external service to have it take a long time so you can test you get the expected error.